# Table layout in android apps

Tags: android

I am creating one apps in which i want to use two row. but when i write this code it is not showing any output.it showing this error in the logcat file .**"Requires development platform xx but this is a release platform."**can any one help on this topic.

```
public  class SongsActivity extends Activity{

    DemoView demoview ;
    DemoView2 finalview;
    DemoView3 dview;
    DemoView4 deview;

    ViewFlipper c ;
    TableLayout d;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.songs_layout);
        demoview = new DemoView(this);
        finalview = new DemoView2(this);
        dview= new DemoView3(this);
        deview = new DemoView4(this);
         d= new TableLayout(this);

         TableRow rw1=new TableRow(this);
         TableRow rw2=new TableRow(this);
        c=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
        c.addView(demoview,0);
        c.addView(finalview, 1);
        c.addView(dview, 2);
        c.addView(deview, 3);
        c.setAutoStart(true);
        c.setFlipInterval(500);
        c.startFlipping();
        rw1.addView(c);
        rw2.addView(c);
        d.addView(rw2);
        d.addView(rw1);
        setContentView(d);
    }
```

Comment: I am creating a new android application am using the table layout.  i coded the program correctly. when I run the application it is showing a error in the logcat. Error is as follow "W/PackageParser(59): /data/app/vmdl25887.tmp (at Binary XML file line #6): Requires development platform xx but this is a release platform." 
Can anyone help on this I am stuck in this from two days

Answer (score 0):

i have got the answer of this question so i think i should share this with you all.in this it is showing a error  of avd .it means your program is run on the higher emulator .you should change the version of the emulator.it can be done through your mainfest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.androidtablayout"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```